# Custom jQuery selectors that doesn't start with ":"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

We all know that it's possible to define custom jQuery selectors that start with `:`. For example:

```
// :textfield definition
$.expr[':'].textfield = function(obj) {
  return $(obj).is("input[type='text']");
};

// Use
$(":textfield").css({"background-color": "#700"});
```

Just out of curiosity, is it possible to define a custom jQuery selector that doesn't start with `:` ?

Comment: Do you have an example of what you had in mind? If you simply use a word without the `:`, Sizzle will interpret it as an element selector.

Comment: In case Sizzle cannot find the element selector, it could be nice if it checked custom elements as the final option.

Comment: If by custom elements you mean something like `<foo></foo>`, then it does. http://jsfiddle.net/ncx7f/ Though I'm not sure if you need to do a hack to get IE to work. I think in older versions I think you need to do a `document.createElement('foo')` to get them to be recognized. Or maybe that hack is to get CSS to work. I don't remember.

Comment: I meant something like `$("checkedbox")` to be a checked checkbox (rather than `<checkedbox>...</checkedbox>`.

Comment: I see what you mean. The trouble would be that if it first searched for `<checkedbox>` elements, and didn't find any, it wouldn't know if you actually wanted `<checkedbox>` elements, and should return none, or if you wanted the special behavior. Even if you could define the special behavior, it would still be possible that you were actually searching for an element that happened to have the same name. That's why they need a special syntax like `:` to clarify intent. I'm sure you could hack Sizzle to include that behavior, but I don't think it would be worth it.

Comment: ...also, keep in mind that custom selectors of any type do not let you take advantage of the speed bump you get with standard valid CSS selectors. When they're valid, Sizzle uses `querySelectorAll` if the browser supports it (and most browsers do). I'd recommend that you avoid proprietary selectors of all types, including the ones that are bundled in Sizzle by default.

Comment: I agree regarding the first part. But, are you saying that using things like `:checked`, `:visible`, and `:my_own`, is a bad idea because they don't use `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: Well, `:checked` is valid for `qSA`, but the other two (as well as a bunch of other Sizzle selectors) are not. So yes, my opinion is that those are to be avoided because `querySelectorAll` can't use them. Ultimately we're very close to eliminating the need for JavaScript based selector engines. If you don't support FF3 and IE6/7, you can eliminate them right now if you eliminate the proprietary selectors.

Comment: What do you mean by "eliminating the need for JavaScript based selector engines"? What are the alternatives?

Comment: The alternative is native DOM selection. The most common (because they're widely supported) are `getElementById` and `getElementsByTagName`. But now browsers have `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll`, which take CSS style selectors. [SizzleJS](http://sizzlejs.com/) is a JavaScript based selector engine. In these engines (fancy term for code library) JavaScript is used to select from the DOM instead of the native code (usually C++) that's used to implement the JavaScript environment. This means that it will almost always be slower. Example to come...

Comment: ...For example, imagine you want all the elements in the document with `class="foo"`. To use native code, you'd use `document.getElementsByClassName("foo");`. Because it is native code, it will be very fast. But if the browser doesn't support that method, you'd need to hack it. You'd do something like `var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*')` to fetch all elements, then you iterate over them to filter the ones that have your class. Because the filter is done in JavaScript, it will be slower than if it could be done with native code.

Comment: I see what you say. But, in case the speed is not a problem, I think it's not a bad idea to use things like `:visible` and `:my_own`. It's more readable and shorter code, and fun!

Comment: Yes, that's a matter of personal preference. My most compelling reason is not so much the speed aspect, but rather the ability to not have to load code that isn't necessary. Imagine if jQuery/Sizzle didn't have the proprietary selectors. They would be able to drop a big chunk of code from the library as soon as they stop supporting IE6/7 (probably within a couple years). But now that's almost impossible. From the individual developer's perspective, they are less reliant on a library if they become accustomed to using native code. But agin, it's a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what I have seen, I think the answer is: no.